# iterate through each input element on the page using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I iterate through each input element on the page using jQuery and print its values with attribute name ending with `Phone` for example

```
<input type="text" value="0" name="aPhone">
<input type="text" value="1" name="1Phone">
<input type="text" value="2" name="kPhone">
...
<input type="text" value="100" name="xPhone">
```

Comment: "*[Print its] values*" where? In response to what event? What have you tried, because - and without wanting to be offensive - this is relatively easy to do, and search for. You have a reputation of *almost* 2,000 (as I write this), you should - by *now* - know to post your best efforts and clearly state what problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

loop through and write outputs to console (you said print - not sure where you want it to go, but just change console.log() to something else):

```
$("input[name$='Phone']").each(function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the values into an array via `.map` (Ends with selector: https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)

```
var vals = $("input[name$='Phone']").map(function() { return this.value }).get();
```